# How to check mail open rate using google analytic?

Tags: email, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The problems is since the mail is not an actual html page putting in webserver

The problems are:

1. How can i use the google analytics to check the open rate of the mail?
2. IF i use a random code eg. newsletter?code='sadsd' I can actually know who have opened the email?
3. Can i view the result by capture the data instead of login to google and view.

   Thank you for any kind of help/ experience sharing.

Comment: Are you talking about an email campaign?

Answer (score 0):

- How can i use the google analytics to check the open rate of the mail?
- IF i use a random code eg. newsletter?code='sadsd' I can actually know who have opened the email?

---

You can't just write something and get something. First of all, if your question is referring to email campaigns then there is a well structured way to achieve this. You can use  [this for reference.](http://www.webmarketcentral.com/email_campaign_tracking.htm)

---

- Can i view the result by capture the data instead of login to google and view?

---

Yes, by using GA-API , you can extract the data, store it in database and view it in your desired format.Also for testing purpose, by using tools like Omnibug or Charles you can test what values are getting passed to the google analytics server (through the Google Analytics Code placed to capture the data(from user interaction) and pass the data (to GA server)).

*Pardon me if I misunderstood your question.

---